# UpsertDE with Composite Primary Key for Journey Activity Tracker

Tags: email, journeybuilder, upsert, activityhistory, subscriber-key

I'm attempting to create a Journey Activity tracker for a DE with a Composite Primary key of [Subscriber Key], ContractID, and ContactId. Here is what I've attempted to insert within each email and it works great at the first instance for a [Subscriber Key]/ContractId/ContactId combination. However, once I attempt to add additional rows to the DE/Journey, which have the same [Subscriber Key] and ContactID but a different ContractId, the upsert updates the original instance of [Subscriber Key]/ContractID/ContactId instead of the new record. What am I missing or misunderstanding?

%%[
VAR @contractId, @contactId, @subscriberKey

SET @contractID = AttributeValue('ContractId')
SET @contactID = AttributeValue('ContactId')
SET @SubscriberKey = _subscriberkey

UpsertDE('DE_Name',3,'Subscriber Key', @SubscriberKey,'ContractId',@contractId,'ContactId',@contactId,'EM1',NOW())

]%%

Note: Subscriber Key is named as "Subscriber Key" within the Database and I've also checked and re-checked naming for the fields for ContractId and ContactId.

Comment: Did you add the composite primary key after initial creation? If so try deleting and recreating the de with the composite PK from the beginning

Comment: Yes, the composite primary key has been in place all along but I’m still going to give this a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to confirm that I had the UpsertDE coded properly. I ended up setting up the journey audience to bring people in as a Filter each day followed by a query of all records in that current filter that adds a row to a Journey Tracker with the Customer/Contact/SubKey as primary key. Then the UpsertDE is updating the EM1, EM2, etc. fields by matching up the Customer/Contact/Subkey. The extra query may or may not be necessary but it seems to work for me so I'm sticking with it.